# Retrieving all users with specified permission

Tags: permissions

With a `$user` object, we can verify the user against a permission setting with the `can()` method. However, how can I retrieve all users who have a specific permission, including those under a group with the permission.

This needs to be generic PHP code as it's located in a service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a clean or particularly efficient way of doing this using Craft's current services.

It'd have to be something like:

```
1. Grab all users
2. Loop through them calling craft()->userPermissions->doesUserHavePermission()
3. If true, save user in success array.
```

Alternatively you could use [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) to query the database directly for the info you're looking for.